# password protected post policy

Tags: functions, wp-admin, users, security, password

I'm looking for a way to add policy about POST password.

**Password specifications :**

**12** characters in length, **1** uppercase letter,  **1** lowercase letter,  **1**     number, and  1 special character.

Is there a hook to add on function.php to do it?

This question is about password protected posts and not USER password.

Comment: Not really, my question  is about POST password not USER password

Comment: what is "post password"? do you mean password protected posts?

Comment: I think it is the password protection for the posts, isn't it?

Comment: Yes password protected posts!

Answer (score 0):

I've had a look at Wordpress' core code and couldn't find anything really useful to add a filter on the post password.

You could use the filter `wp_insert_post_empty_content`, it is used to check whether the required fields of the post are set or not (e.g.: title).

Here is an example on how it could be used:

```
function myfunc_password_policy( $maybe_empty, $postarr ) {
    $result = $maybe_empty;

    // is the value of the field $postarr['post_password'] complicated enough?
    // ...

    return $result;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_empty_content', 'myfunc_password_policy', 9999, 2);
```

The problem is that there will be no relevant error message displayed in the admin if the password is refused.

Another way might be to use Javascript to hook the `click` event on the `publish/update` button and send an ajax request with the value of the password field:

```
function myfunc_check_password_policy(){
    global $post;

    if('post' === $post->post_type){
        echo "
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                //Click handler - you might have to bind this click event another way
                $('input#publish, input#save-post').on('click', function(){
                    var password_value = $('#post_password').val();
                    var ajax_url = '" . admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) . "';

                    // send an ajax request to check if the password
                    $.ajax( 
                        ajax_url,
                        {
                            action:'check_protected_post_password',
                            // ...
                        }
                    );
                });
            });
        </script>";
    }
}
add_action('admin_head-post.php', 'myfunc_check_password_policy');
add_action('admin_head-post-new.php', 'myfunc_check_password_policy');
```

The code samples haven't been tested and obviously need some improvement but you should get the idea.

These are the possibilities I could think of to solve your problem. Good luck :)

Comment: not sure why do you want to send the AJAX request to the server, why not to just check the field client side. As for handling errors, you can always set a cookie to indicate an error

Comment: Because I assumed the password policy would be implemented in PHP. If it can be done on the client side, then sure, no need for an ajax request.

Comment: it should be done both sides. It is faster to have a response from avalidating JS code than wait for the at least 1 second delay required for ajax requests on most site (and that is probably optimistic estimate). In any case the ajax is not enough unless you are also blocking the submit while it is going on.

Comment: I agree but it should be noted that the javascript solution will not work when creating a post programmatically.

Comment: yeh, not sure this is what the OP looking for, but you have a point